# Move my Application Window?

Tags: android, window, move

We have one android application, and then the width and height as the `wrap_content`.

My XML Code is `main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:contentDescription="Move" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My Activity Code is `MoveApplicationActivity.java`

```
package com.move;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class MoveApplicationActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

My `MoveApplication Manifest.xml` code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.move"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MoveApplicationActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Please work out my sample code, don't forget to add this bold line to `Manifest.xml`.

**android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog.NoActionBar"**

I have no idea, How do Move Application window. Please Guide me through programmatically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you me by move...

Comment: My application window width size is 50 and height size is 50. So my application window is a very small size. How to move my application as `X and Y` direction.

Comment: This is how you can move the location of a toast.  I have no idea in your case though, but it might help you.

    final Toast def = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Toasty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    def.setGravity(0, 0, -200);
    def.show()

Comment: I am not asking about the Toast. For example my android mobile device size is 240 * 400. My application window size is 50 * 50. Move window direction (x, y) `setOnTouchListener()` how to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this through normal means.

An Activity will cover the whole screen, you cannot change that.

What you could try to do, is create an Activity with a transparent theme. Then you could create a DialogFragment with a certain width and height.

This will make your App appear to be a certain size when it is actually taking the whole screen up.

I do not think you can control the X, Y coordinates of the location of the DialogFragment though.